# Avoid landing page redirects issue in wordpress multisite

Tags: multisite, optimization

Recently I configured my website for https and redirected http to https but now in google page speed, I am getting issue of Too many redirects!

Can be checked at: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=peterkentconsulting.com&tab=desktop

And Google explains: Your page has 2 redirects,
site is wordpress multisite. Please help me to remove those redirects..

Thanks
[image: snapshot of google pagespeed]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved by editing site url at `wp_site` and `wp_options` tables in database.